# Does Vowpal Wabbit support adding and removing features during training?

Tags: c++, feature-selection, vowpalwabbit

I would seem to think that it is fine at supporting adding features while training by just expanding the weight vector, and from a few tests it looks like it does exactly that.

I am also aware that the feature names are hashed by VW and therefore I was thinking that it is possible to remove features while training as well, but I cannot seem to confirm this in the code and have been having trouble testing via indices and weight values.

Is there a definitive answer on these issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you train with `--save_resume`, you can continue the training (loading the previously trained model with `-i`) with different training data (with more features) and/or with different command line options for generating more features (e.g. `--quadratic` or `--interactions`). This is equivalent to adding features "while training".

There are also some reductions which automatically add more features during training. Currently, I am only aware of [--stage_poly](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#stagewise-polynomial-options), but maybe there are more.